# onClick handler to change color of an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react element like this:

```
const [customStyle, setCustomStyles] = React.useState()

const handleSelect = (data) => {
    const custom = {
      border: '3px solid black',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      padding: 20,
    }

    setCustomStyles(custom)
  }

return (
     <div
              key={nanoid()}
              className={styles.professorsContainer}
              style={customStyle}
              onClick={() => handleSelect(data)}
            >
              <p>
                {data.date} {data.content}
              </p>
            </div>

)
```

Where I want to change the color of the  `{data.date} - {data.content}` when I click on the text, but it does not want to change! any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to be wrong with your block structure. Styles can be applied in the way you described. Find a working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/kind-minsky-uq5w3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The problem is still persist, but one thing, I'm mapping an array and then rendering child component and try to apply that condition on the child components, would that affect on it?

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you include that code as well? Because as illustrated by how it is working in the sandbox, the code snippet you uploaded doesn't contain the cause of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The correct CSS property for background color would be background-color.

Comment: it is not about changing only the color, but the whole styles are not applicable